# Is there any way you can do this in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ide, javabeans

[image: Screenshot]

Did not find any extension that does stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

In the preferences *Java > Editor > **Code Minings*** make sure *Enable Code Minings* and ***Show method parameter names*** are enabled for that.

Opened editors must be reopened in order for the *Code Minings* to become visible.